# Given below is error while installing dlib in python 3.6.6. I am using command "python setup.py install" inside dlib 19.15 folder in windows 10.

Tags: python, windows, cmake, dlib

Given below is the error. Please help. An error occured while installation. I am using dlib ver 19.15 . I think cmake is not configured properly. Can u guys check and tell where is the error? I am using cmake version 3.12 . I am using python 3.6.6 and pip version 10 (not latest). I am using windows 10 core i5. I am frustrated.

```
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing dlib.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to dlib.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to dlib.egg-info\top_level.txt
package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
reading manifest file 'dlib.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'dlib.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
Building extension for Python 3.6.6 (v3.6.6:4cf1f54eb7, Jun 27 2018, 03:37:03) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake          C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\dlib-19.15\tools\python -    DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\dlib-19.15\build\lib.win-amd64-3.6 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\dlib-19.15\build\lib.win-amd64-3.6 -A x64'
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  Generator

    NMake Makefiles

  does not support platform specification, but platform

    x64

  was specified.


CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Lib/site-        packages/dlib-19.15/build/temp.win-amd64-3.6/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 257, in <module>
    'Topic :: Software Development',
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 129, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File     "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 67, in run
    self.do_egg_install()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 109, in do_egg_install
    self.run_command('bdist_egg')
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 172, in run
    cmd = self.call_command('install_lib', warn_dir=0)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 158, in call_command
    self.run_command(cmdname)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install_lib.py", line 11, in run
    self.build()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\command\install_lib.py", line 107, in build
    self.run_command('build_ext')
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "setup.py", line 133, in run
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "setup.py", line 170, in build_extension
    subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 291, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\Lib\\site-packages\\dlib-19.15\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\Lib\\site-packages\\dlib-19.15\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.6', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\Lib\\site-packages\\dlib-19.15\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.6', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

It is fixed now. I only had to install Visual Studio as cmake requires it for .cxx files compilation.